Difference Between Gaussian Process and Gaussian Process Regression?
I am having difficulty understanding the following point: Is a Gaussian Process the same thing as a  Gaussian Process Regression?
For example, define a Gaussian Process like this:
$$f(x) \sim GP(m(x), k(x, x'))$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} f(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_m) \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} m(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ m(x_m) \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k(x_1, x_1) & \cdots & k(x_1, x_m) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ k(x_m, x_1) & \cdots & k(x_m, x_m) \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
Given some real data, I could estimate the parameters of this Gaussian Process using Maximum Likelihood Estimation:
$$
p(y | X, \theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (y - m(X))^T \Sigma^{-1} (y - m(X))\right)
$$
$$
L(\mu, \Sigma | D) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} p(y_i | x_i, w_i, z_i, \theta)
$$
From here, I can derive the equations to determine the mean and variance of some new data points.
I am just confused - why is this called a "Regression"? There are no beta regression coefficients being estimated. Isn't this name of Regression kind of misleading here?
